# Mega menu slide down required on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, megamenu

I'm using a Mega Dropdown css based menu. Instead of shows the items on hover i want to display it on click. I also want the slide down to be there till i click any where else on the page or on a close button on the slide down(I plan to add this).

Your help and any feedback is appreciated

Thanks

LJ

Comment: What do you think about using jQuery for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an Accordion menu for this. It allows you to show the submenus on click, and the submenus slide out as well, like the one here.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu.htm